# Sorting in ElasticSearch using NodeJS Client

Tags: node.js, sorting, elasticsearch

I'm trying to sort the results from a query based on a field, and for some reason, it never sorts properly.  Below is the example of the query:

```
  starting request {
   "method": "POST",
   "path": "/index/library/_search",
   "query": {
      "from": 0,
      "size": 10,
      "sort": "[{\"title\":{\"order\":\"asc\"}}]",
      "q": "\"rules\""
     }
   }
```

Which generates this URL:

http://localhost:9200/index/library/_search?from=0&size=10&sort=%5B%7B%22title%22%3A%7B%22order%22%3A%22asc%22%7D%7D%5D&q=%22rules%22

I've tried a number of different ways of structuring the sort, but for whatever reason, it never returns in alphabetical order.

Am I structuring the sort portion incorrectly?  Or am I missing something?

Edit:

```
    search(type, query, options) {
    let params = {
        index: this.indexName,
        type: type,
        from: options.from || 0,
        size: options.size || 500,
        sort: options.sort
    };


    if (JSON.parse(query).hasOwnProperty('query')) {
        params.body = query;
    } else {
        params.q = query;
    }

    return this.client.search(params);
}
```

Query:

```
Elasticsearch DEBUG: 2017-05-04T15:55:00Z
starting request {
  "method": "POST",
  "path": "/index/library/_search",
  "query": {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "sort": "title : asc",
    "q": "rules"
  }
}


Elasticsearch TRACE: 2017-05-04T15:55:00Z
 -> POST http://localhost:9200/index/library/_search?
  from=0&size=10&sort=title%20%3A%20asc&q=rules
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
  starting request {
   "method": "POST",
   "path": "/index/library/_search",
   "query": {
      "from": 0,
      "size": 10,
      "sort": "title:asc",        <---- change this
      "q": "rules"
     }
   }
```

That will generate this URL which should be more correct

http://localhost:9200/index/library/_search?from=0&size=10&sort=title%3Aasc&q=rules

Comment: Yep, I've tried that as well.  Doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code you have and also which Node.js module you're using?

Comment: I added the code above.  Using elasticsearch.js 12.1.3

Comment: That's what I get for doing two things at once ;)

Comment: It's an object property:  'sort': `${sort} : asc` where sort is the title of the field I want to sort on.

Comment: It looks like your sort is a string instead of an object

Comment: In your example, your sort is a string, no?  "title: asc"?

Comment: The lib also returns an exception that sort needs to be a string, array, or number, if you pass it an object.

Comment: Yes, in mine it's a pure string, but in yours it's a stringified JSON, while it should be an object. Try not to stringify it.

Comment: I do not stringify it anymore, it still doesn't sort properly.

Comment: It would be nice if you could print out the query that is generated. When setting up your client simply your `trace` level: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/13.0/logging.html#logging-customization

Comment: Added the trace

Comment: Well, now it's clear, you simply need to remove the spaces in your sort parameter, `"sort": "title : asc",` should be `"sort": "title:asc",`

Comment: Yep, just figured that out this morning.  Came here to post the answer.  Seems odd that that would be the issue...